# Material ui: change duration of Skeleton animations

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

mui's `<Skeleton>` components use pulse or wavy animations.

Is there a way to speed up this animation a bit, e.g. by changing the duration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, fairly easily actually! Assuming you're using the latest version of MUI.

```js
<Skeleton width={400} height={100} sx={{ animationDuration: "0.3s" }} />
```

[Read more about the SX prop here.](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content)